How to place stub files in dedicated folder?
Let me explain my issue with an example.
I have two Python files, module.py and main.py.
# module.py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class User:
    user_id: str = field(repr=False)
    name: str = field(init=False)
    password: str = field(init=False, repr=False)
    birth_year: int = field(init=False)
    age: int = field(init=False)

    def __post__init__(self):
        # ? Fetching user information from the database using "user_id"
        # ? and assigning value to variables
        ...

# main.py
from module import User

user = User("userid")

and 1 stub file
# module.pyi
class User:
    """User Object - Deal with single User"""

    name: str
    password: str
    birth_year: int
    age: int

    def __init__(self, user_id: str) -> None: ...

When I place both of these module.py and module.pyi on the same level, VSCode is picking this .pyi file and properly providing type-hinting (and docstring) based on the stub, but if I move this .pyi file to another directory (say directory stubs dedicated for stubs file) VSCode is not picking it up.
So, my question is how can I make IDE (VSCode in my case) to accurately pick this stubs file and associate with relevant file?
I am using Pylance as the language-server, if that is relevant.

Check out this page: Python settings reference. There are a bunch of settings that look promising, like python.analysis.stubPath. I'm using Jedi myself, which the Python extension only provides python.autoComplete.extraPaths, and I can't seem to get it to override the module code (but I can get it working if the module doesn't exist).
